# JavaScript Validation needed for this form, it does not work whatever I try

Tags: javascript, php

This form needs to calculate cost for each course (which is not done yet). It needs JavaScript Validation, and PHP for Username and Password info to go somewhere. The credentials will be used in a PHP login. Can you help?

```
<form form name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type=text name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F"> Female
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="birthday">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" name="bday" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="username">Create Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password" name="name">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="username" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Comments">Address</label>
    </p>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="Address" id="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <br>
    <p>
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Enter your postcode" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="contactnumber">Contact Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="contactnumber" placeholder="Enter your number" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="select">Select Course</label>
    </p>
    <select id="course" name="courses">
        <option value="000" selected="selected">[Select course]</option>
        <option value="screenplay">Screenplay FL0330 04-01-16</option>
        <option value="camerawork">Camerawork FL566 05-01-16</option>
        <option value="soundrecording">Sound Recording FB700 06-01-16</option>
        <option value="lighting">Lighting FN250 11-01-16</option>
        <option value="editing">Editing FB420 12-01-16</option>
        <option value="3dgraphics">3D Graphics FA554 13-01-16</option>
        <option value="makeup">Make up and Prosthetics FA128 15-01-16</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Now">
</form>
```

Comment: you can use jquery plugin its easy and simple.

Comment: type "validation plugin in jquery" in google

Comment: cheers mate, I'll give it a go

Comment: Needs to be done on JavaScript though, thats the brief. Hmmmmmmmm

Comment: Keep in mind that clientside JavaScript validation is in no way bulletproof, a user can just edit the JavaScript and throw out all validation. So don't depend on it for providing security / constraints.

Comment: Could you please also write what you already tried till now in order to achieve the expected result?
Did you already created a javascript to perform this validation? 
If so, could you copy/paste the script here and explain what is not performed correctly by your script ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've submitted the assignment, don't worry about it... and I am aware that JavaScript Validation has major security flaws but it was only part of an assignment prototype, not for commercial use. Thanks